Why does Ripley buy six train tickets?
In episode 4 of the Ripley miniseries with Andrew Scott, he returns to Atrani from San Remo, clears out the villa, and then goes to Naples and books six first-class tickets on the train to Rome. Why does he book so many tickets?

Probably so he is alone in his train compartment, which usually consists of 6 seats.

In the next scene we see that he's bought enough tickets to allow him the exclusive use of an entire passenger compartment.

He then spends the journey practicing forging Greenleaf's signature, something he couldn't do if there were other passengers sharing the car.


I’ve not seen the show, but one might wonder why he’d choose a moving train – a notoriously difficult, if not impossible, place to write, draw or do anything else that requires a steady hand on paper – as the location in which to forge a signature, rather than, say, doing it in the villa he’d just cleared out, which was presumably stationary.

@JanusBahsJacquet - In the novel he has all sorts of difficulty with the signature. He can't ever seem to get it quite right. Practicing it under a range of conditions seems like a pretty good idea, and train cars aren't all that wobbly

Oh, I see – you meant that he spends the journey practicing the forged signature. That makes more sense; I thought you meant that he had a specific document where he needed to forge the signature and chose to do that on the train. Train cars are definitely less wobbly than just 20 years ago, but I personally still find it a real challenge to write legibly on a moving train, much less emulate someone’s signature.
